# Complex numbers' arguments. Obtuse or Acute?

Tags: complex-numbers

Are the arguments of complex numbers always acute or can there exist obtuse arguments? Or is only the acute version taken every time an argument exceeds $\frac{\pi}{2} \textbf{rad}$ ?

Comment: Complex number arguments takes value between $(-\pi, \pi]$. So they may well take obtuse values as well!

Comment: Formally, we can define the rwal function $arg(a,b)$ as this:

Comment: Let $(a,b)$ be the ordered pair of real numbers representing a point on a circle whose center is represented by the ordered pair $(0,0)$. Then $arg(a,b)$ represents the number of radians in the arc connecting $(a,b)$ and $(0,\sqrt(a^2+b^2)$

One corollary of this definition is that $\cos(arg(a,b))+isin(arg(a,b))=\frac{e^{iarg(a,b)}}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that by definition the argument of  a complex number is the angle between the positive real axis and the line joining the point to the origin. The principal value of $\operatorname{Arg}(z)$ is usually defined in the interval $(-\pi,\pi]$ and the set of all arguments of $z$ is $\arg(z) = \{\operatorname{Arg}(z) + 2\pi n\;|\; n \in \mathbb Z\}$.

[image]

What are the arguments of $z=-1$ or of $z=-\frac{\sqrt 2}2+i\frac{\sqrt 2}2$?

Maybe your doubt arises from the fact that for $x\neq 0$

- $\operatorname{Arg}(z)=\arctan{\frac y x}\in (-\pi/2,\pi/2)$

but recall that that expression is valid only for $x>0$ and we need to add $\pm \pi$ to obtain $\operatorname{Arg}(z)$or use the function $\arctan2(y,x)$.

Comment: But, can I assume that the argument can never be a reflex angle? So is it always 2π – [that reflex angle]?

Comment: @Ramana Yes one can also define $\operatorname{Arg}(z)\in [0,2\pi)$ for the principal argument but usually $(-\pi, \pi]$ is assumed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the prompt replies!